# Problem in soldering a kit

Tags: soldering

I bought a printed board online with components that I should solder. I had the map, and I soldered them, but when I tested the circuit with a 12 V battery it didn't work. The circuit is an audio frequency amplifier, with a mini microphone and speaker. [Here is the link about it](http://ekt2.com/products/productdetails?ProductId=6de169e7-f637-416a-97f1-b6e9207f39fa).

Is there any problem with the soldering part?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are many problems with this board.

Looking at the bottom:

- It appears that the solder is not "wetting" the copper traces to any significant degree, probably leaving you with a least a few open connections. You need to apply heat equally to the traces and the leads when soldering.

Looking at the top:

- The broken wire on R6 is an obvious problem. That needs to be fixed.
- The soldering on the back of the microphone looks particularly bad. Are you sure you haven't shorted it out?
- Most importantly, an electret microphone capsule like the one you show requires a DC bias in order to work at all. This amplifier is not designed to provide such a bias. Try it with an ordinary dynamic microphone.

Comment: Ok thanks. So the trace and the solder should be wet so the connection is set on ?

Comment: Yes. [Here's a decent tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-guide-excellent-soldering/common-problems)